# NSOperation with NSTimer loop how to stop it

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have NSOperationQueue that runs on another thread than the whole application. I'm adding NSOperation to the queue that in main has

```
-(void)main{
     [self updatePallets];
     NSTimer * timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 5.0 target:self selector: @selector(updatePallets) userInfo: nil repeats: Yes];
     NSRunLoop * runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
     [runLoop addTimer:timer forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes];
     [runLoop run];
}
```

And it works fine as I wanted. But how to cancel this type of operation. On My main thread I want to for example do something like this:

```
[queue cancelAllOperations];
[queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
```

And I want to hang main thread and wait until it is finished. And then perform some actions.  But It does not cancel any operation (there'is only one with the timer) what I should do? I tried also to add new operation to the queue after dispatcher pop time, but still can't stop it.

Comment: Did you invalidate timer?
`[timer invalidate]`

Comment: No I just tried to cancel the operation. So I need to have the reference to the timer... Is It possible to cancelAllOperations and then it stop all the operations? Can I add some conditions to runLoop?

Comment: I am not sure about cancelAllOperations. But with NSTimer, I am using `[timer invalidate]`

Comment: I created `@property (strong, atomic) NSTimer * timer`
and method `-(void)stopOperation{[self.timer invalidate]}`
after that I get all operations from queue and setting them `stopOperation`
then I put there cancelAllOperations, and then once again get all the operations from queue and they have `timer = nil`  so it should be stopped and removed from queue ?

Comment: It seams not leaving the `main` in opearation

Comment: Humh, I will upvote this question for others bro can notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something like:

> Manually removing all known input sources and timers from the run loop is not a guarantee that the run loop will exit. OS X can install and remove additional input sources as needed to process requests targeted at the receiver’s thread. Those sources could therefore prevent the run loop from exiting.
>
> If you want the run loop to terminate, you shouldn't use this method. Instead, use one of the other run methods and also check other arbitrary conditions of your own, in a loop.

So I added `while` loop. But I don't know if it is efficient...

```
while(self.timer.valid && [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]]);
```